# What is the right way to store a value(s) of a row (from i to n) to be used later in code? (VBA Lookup/matching function)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA, so your help is really appreciated.  My code is taking a partial value from a string in each row of a range (in sheet "Lookup"), looking up this partial value in a range (in sheet "CF"), and outputting the value corresponding to the partial value (but located in a different column) to a specific range in sheet "Lookup".  The following code works for the very first instance of a loop and then spits out an error "Object variable not set or With missing".  It looks like the issue is Val variable, but I can't get this to work.  Could you please help me understand, if I'm not defining Val correctly? I'm using Val to store the row number that corresponds to the position of the value I'm trying to look up. Perhaps there's a faster way to do this lookup (the value of interest is in a different column from lookup value)? Thank you!

```
Sub CF_Lookup()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim Str As String
Dim lRange As Range
Dim Val As Long

With Sheets("Lookup")
      Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      For i = 2 To Lastrow
          With .Range("A" & i & ":A" & Lastrow)
              Str = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 8)
              Set lRange = Worksheets("CF").Range("A:M").Find(Str, Lookat:=xlPart)
              Val(i) = lRange.Row
              Worksheets("Lookup").Range("P" & i).Value = Worksheets("CF").Range("M" & Val(i)).Value
          End With
      Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Val=lRange.Row` ? `Val` is not an array so cannot have elements. Also your `With` is redundant.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Would it make sense to set up Val as an array to store row number, which then becomes an input to a range reference? Or is there another way to store row numbers for each iteration?

Comment: The error 91 is caused by the unconditional `lRange.Row` member call, whenever the `Range.Find` call fails to find `Str`, the function returns `Nothing` - you need to make sure whether `Not lRage Is Nothing` is true before you can make member calls against `lRange`.

Comment: Yes if you need to store them all, an array is the way to go. You should also check first that `str` is found before assigning Val to avoid an error.